# Apache shiro unit test with checkPermission passes regardless of stubbed permission

Tags: unit-testing, shiro

Running spring boot 1.5.12 with Shiro starter 1.4.0

Trying to write up some unit tests to test a static class which checks permissions using the checkPermission of the Subject interface.

I'm mocking the shiro subject and stubbing the isPermitted method to return false for specific permission string... but for some reason, it passes when Subject.checkPermission is executed.

```
Subject subjectUnderTest = mock(Subject.class);
when(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
when(subjectUnderTest.isPermitted(eq("review:edit:regional"))).thenReturn(false);
setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
subjectUnderTest.checkPermission("review:edit:regional");
```

I'm fairly new to Mockito but in this case was expecting AuthorizationException to be thrown by checkPermission given the isPermitted stub returning false.

If i change the implementation to use isPermitted, then test runs as expected..but current implementation is using checkPermission...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `checkPermission()` of the [`Subject`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html) interface will not call `isPermitted()` on itself but on the abstract [`AuthorizingRealm`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthorizingRealm.html). The callchain for `checkPermission()` is like the following:

```
Subject.checkPermissions()->
    DelegatingSubject.checkPermissions()->
        Authoriser.checkPermission()->
            AuthorizingRealm.checkPermission()->
            AuthorizingRealm.isPermitted()
```

Therefore, mocking `isPermitted()` on the `Subject` will have no effect since `checkPermission()` will never call it on this object. To achieve the expected behavior, you have to mock the method on the `AuthorizingRealm` or alternatively on the `AuthorizingSecurityManager` incase calls to your `SecurityManager` are available under test.

Comment: Thanks. I was playing with the Mocked subject.checkPermission then got into mockito's approach to void stubbing.. so seems the proper approach here is using doNothing and doThrow to mock the checkPermission pass and failure tests..where doThrow() will throw a shiro AuthorizationException.